# Clearest way to cast a string bool value to bool

Tags: c#, string

I have a function that returns a string true/false value as a bool, what is the best/clearest way to return this? I want to default that anything other than 0 or a case insensitive false is true. This is what I have, but I feel its poorly readable yet functional.

```
bool isTrue = !resultString.Equals("FALSE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
if(isTrue)
    isTrue = !resultString.Equals("0");
return isTrue;
```

I feel there has to be a better way to go about this.

Comment: Why does it return it as a string? Can you change the code to return a bool type instead?

Comment: `return !(resultString.Equals("FALSE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || resultString.Equals("0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`?

Comment: @igor its reading from a csv that may or may not have been human typed

Comment: `bool.TryParse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is `Convert.ToBoolean();`

```
bool isTrue;
try
{
    isTrue = Convert.ToBoolean(resultstring);
}
catch
{
    isTrue = true;
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToBoolean_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is not a valid boolean value is cast to "true", otherwise "0" or "FALSE" are cast correctly. Same with "1" and "TRUE"

```
bool isTrue;
if(!bool.TryParse(resultString, out bool result))
{
    isTrue = true;
} 
else isTrue = result;

//Sample output would be as follows 
//resultString="0"        => isTrue=false
//resultString="1"        => isTrue=true 
//resultString="False"    => isTrue=false
//resultString="True"     => isTrue=true 
//resultString="Apple"    => isTrue=true 
//resultString="House"    => isTrue=true
```

Comment: wouldn't that return an uninitialized isTrue on a failed parse?

Comment: booleans default to false, so it won't be uninitialised. Though in this example, on failed parse, the `isTrue=true` is run. So if the text is not a valid boolean at all, you will get a true at the end

Comment: @leviClouser `TryParse` will initialize `isTrue` to the default value (`0`) if the parsing is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, similar to the others

```
public static bool Parse(string input)
{
    bool result;
    return input != "0" && (!bool.TryParse(input, out result) || result);
}
```

Or if you're using C#7 or greater, it's just one line:

```
public static bool Parse(string input)
{
    return input != "0" && (!bool.TryParse(input, out var result) || result);
}
```